# replace dots with new line with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the 4 dots(....) in my String with new line (\n) by using regex in the replace method.

orange...apple....banana --> should be pirnted as:

```
orange
apple
banana
```

I have tried the following:

```
get : function(value) {
 value = value.replace(/(...)/g, '\n');
 return value;
}
```

and

```
value.replace(/(\r\n|\n)/g, '....')
```

--> should retrieve 'orange....apple....banana'

Comment: You can split the input string using `'....'` as delimiter then join the pieces using `'\n'` as follows: `get: function(value) { return value.split('....').join('\n'); }`
[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) produces an array of many small strings that [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) glues together to produce the desired output string. **This method is not recommended for large input strings because it uses a lot of memory**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the dot in regular expressions:

```
value = value.replace(/\.{4}/g, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a special character in regex, you'll have to escape it